# Convert each prop of an object to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given this Object :

```
{
 name : 'whale'
 color : 'blue',
 size : 'xxl'
}
```

How do i turn it into ?

```
[
  { name : 'whale' },
  { color : 'blue'},
  { size: 'xxl' }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i found a way after more deep tests

```
Object.entries(myObject).map(([key, val]) => ({[key]: val}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the entries of the object with new objects.

```js
var data = { name : 'whale', color : 'blue', size : 'xxl' },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(keyValue => Object.fromEntries([keyValue]));

console.log(result);
```